# Power Grid - Middle East. Are plants 06, 11, 14 in starting current market removed to the box?

Tags: power-grid

The rules section of Power Grid's Middle East map state :

> At the start of the game and during Step 1, the players do not have
> access to  garbage or nuclear power plants. After preparing the power
> plant market and the power plant stack, remove the power plants "06",
> "11", or "14" (the ones with a plug on the back) if they appear in the
> current market.

Note. Given that the plant numbers to remove are specified, the phrase "the ones with a plug on the back" appears superfluous to me.

**The question**

> Does  one remove these power plants from the game, or does one return
> them to the stack?

Everywhere else in the rules, it is clearly stated when a power plant should be returned to the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "06", "11", or "14" plants are removed to the game box if they come up in the current market during setup or at any later point in step 1.

The parenthetical "(the ones with a plug on the back)" actually holds the key to the answer.  Two lines down in the rules for preparation, it says (emphasis mine):

> **If the removed power plants have a plug on the back, remove them from the game, returning them to the box.** Place the bigger power plants face down below the current power plant stack.

This line is also repeated in the rules for "Auction Power Plants".

---

As an aside, it appears that there is an error in the rulebook regarding the removal of garbage and nuclear power plants during step 1.  The following sentence in the rules for preparation is wrong:

> If the players move [garbage or nuclear plants] into the current market when placing new power plants to replace those removed, remove them from the game, returning them to the box.

This is only accurate regarding power plants with plugs on the back.  Garbage and nuclear power plants with sockets on the back that make it into the current market should be put on the bottom of the deck.  This is specified by the rule quoted previously in this answer, and again in the rules for "Auction Power Plants".